# What is the advantage of Deterministic Policy Gradient over Stochastic Policy Gradient?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient ([DDPG](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971.pdf)) is the state-of-the-art method for reinforcement learning when the action space is continuous. Its core algorithm is [Deterministic Policy Gradient](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/silver14.pdf).

However, after reading the papers and listening to the talk (http://techtalks.tv/talks/deterministic-policy-gradient-algorithms/61098/), I still cannot figure out what the fundamental advantage for Deterministic PG over Stochastic PG is. The talk says it is more suitable for high dimensional actions and easier to train, but why is that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://ai.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 8):

The main reason of policy gradient method is to solve continuous action space problem, which is difficult for Q learning due to the Global Q maximization.

SPG can solve continuous action space problem since it represents the policy by a continuous probability distribution. Since SPG assumes its policy to be a distribution, it needs integral over actions to get the gradient of overall reward. SPG resorts to importance sampling to do this integration.

DPG represents the policy by a deterministic mapping from state to action. It can do it because it is not taking the action of the global greatest Q but it selects actions according to the deterministic mapping(if on policy) while shift this deterministic mapping by the gradient of Q(both on and off policy). The gradient of overall reward then has a form does not needs the integral over actions and it is easier to be computed.

One can say that it seems to be a step back changing from stochastic policy to deterministic policy. But the stochastic policy is first introduced to handle continuous action space only. Deterministic policy now provides another way to handle continuous action space.

My observation is obtained from these papers:

Deterministic Policy Gradient Algorithms

Policy Gradient Methods for Reinforcement Learning with Function Approximation

Continuous Control With Deep Reinforcement Learning

Comment: Do you have any reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

Because the policy is deterministic instead of stochastic, meaning there is only one action that will be selected for each state.

Comment: i interpret it differently. because it is deterministic, it will always select the action with the highest probability, eg np.argmax([x,y,z]. in stochastic networks, it draws from the probability distribution, such that the highest probability action is most likely to be selected, but not always.

Comment: /vin, I think you misunderstood it. As the paper use mu(a | s, th) as action given state and parameters, for 1-dim action, mu would be one real number.